# Jersey Client (2.4) - PUT InputStream but Content-Length = 0

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, put, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm trying to make a request to a `Jersey REST service` which accepts an `InputStream` as an entity using the `PUT` method.

When I do, the Jersey client sets the `Content-Length` header to 0.

The REST service requires that the `Content-Length` is set to the actual size of the stream (IE the size of the file), but, whenever I try to set the `Content-Length` the client throws:

> org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already
>   present

To note - the exception is not thrown when I add the Content-Length header, (at that point, this header doesn't exist), it's thrown (I assume) when `Jersey / Apache HTTPClient` tries to add the `0` header value later.

Stack if it's any help:

> Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:909)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:827)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:326)
>       ... 40 more
>
> Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header
>   already present   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>     ... 42 more

So, any ideas why `Jersey / Apache HTTP Client` sets the `Content-Length` header to 0, and, why I'm not able to override the `Content-Length` header

I'm using:

`Jersey 2.4.1` with the `ApacheConnector`

Thanks in advance

Will

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to answer this:

This is a problem with the ApacheConnector, which will always return -1 for the size of the content, ensuring this value is never set. (This is hardcoded in the getHttpEntity method)

Therefore, if the content-length header is required, one either has to reimplement the ApacheConnector as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157218/jersey-2-0-content-length-not-set) or use a different connector.

I have reported this on the Jersey jira.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2373